# Clarification about the concept of number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

I am reading a book called Numerical Notation: A Comparative History (by Stephen Chrisomalis).

The first chapter (Introduction), second and third paragraph go like this:

> If you look up from this page and examine your surroundings, I am certain that
>   you will encounter at least one instance of numerical notation, probably more.
>   Moreover, unless you have a Roman numeral clock nearby, I am nearly certain
>   that all of the numerals you encounter are those of the Hindu-Arabic or Western 1
>   system. Numerals serve a wide variety of functions: denotation – “Call George,                                                                            876 – 5000”; computation – “21.00 × 1.15 = 24.15”; valuation – “25 cents”; ordina-
>   tion – “1. Wash dishes, 2. Sweep fl oor, 3. Finish manuscript”; and so on. Most of
>   the thousands of numerals we see each day barely register on our conscious minds;
>   regardless, we encounter far more written numbers in our lifetime than we do
>   sunsets, songs, or smiles. Until the past few centuries, the opposite was true for
>   most people.
>
> These ten digits are so prevalent that it is easy to equate our
>   numeral-signs with the set of abstract numbers. In this view, 62 does
>   not merely signify the abstract concept “sixty-two” – it is the raw
>   form of the number itself, the stuff of pure mathematics (or perhaps
>   pure numerology). That these signs are frequently encountered and
>   used in mathematical contexts contributes to the prevalence of such
>   attitudes. According to this view, our numeral-signs constitute
>   abstract number, and other systems (when recognized as such) are
>   simply archaic devia- tions from the abstract entity comprised by
>   these signs.

My question is about the line

> In this view, 62 does not merely signify the abstract concept
>   “sixty-two” – it is the raw form of the number itself, the stuff of
>   pure mathematics (or perhaps pure numerology).

Aren't "the abstract concept “sixty-two” and  "the raw form of the number itself, the stuff of pure mathematics" the same thing: the idea of 62: that which is common between 62 cats and 62 stones?   If not what are they referring to?

Comment: Perhaps the author just wanted to stress the fact that the decimal notation is so ingrained into our minds we can't think about numbers without relating them to the way they are written under this notation

Comment: Yes, the author's point is that people confuse the denotation "62" for the denoted number. Would probably happen less often if people were more used to denotations like 0x3E, 076, LXII and whatnot.

Comment: @ Emisor @DanielFischer Yes that is his point. I just have trouble understanding his illustration: he seems to refer to "the abstract concept “sixty-two” and "the raw form of the number itself" as two different concepts. To me they sound the same. Are they?

Comment: You misunderstand the sentence. `In this view, 62 does not merely signify the abstract concept “sixty-two” – it [the denotation 62] is the raw form of the number itself, the stuff of pure mathematics (or perhaps pure numerology).` The denotation signifies the abstract concept, but some people think the denotation itself _is_ the abstract concept/the raw form of the number.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I get it now. The emphasis is on "signify" :) Thanks!

Comment: @ClementC. I think you might be making a mistake understanding the sentence too. Daniel's explanation makes sense..

Comment: Indeed, reading carefully I was twisting the meaning of "signify." Thanks. (Deleting my earlier comment, as it can only add to the confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string $62$ is distinct from the string $50 + 12$. But the two strings represent a single number. I think the author is suggesting that people often conflate numbers with strings that represent numbers. I read the line with the following emphasis:

> In this view, 62 does not merely *signify* the abstract concept
>   “sixty-two” – it is the raw form of *the number itself*, the stuff of
>   pure mathematics (or perhaps pure numerology).

Anecdotally, it seems true to me that people do indeed conflate numbers with strings. I suspect that this underlies the common discomfort with the fact that $0.999\dotso = 1$. The two strings $0.999\dotso$ and $1$ are not equal, and people sometimes fail to draw a distinction between a number and its decimal expansion(s).

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Fisher already noted, the authors are stressing the difference between the sign and the signified.

When I sign my name at the bottom of this document, I am not putting myself there, and if you happen to delete this document, no harm would come to my physical self. Likewise, when I'm writing '62' here, it is a sign, pointing at the abstract concept (the number 62). It is not the abstract concept which is written down, only a sign referring to it.

Comment: thanks! I got his point, just misunderstood his example.. it's clearer now.

Comment: The nice thing about it, is that medieval philosophy (after Plato) assumed that you do put yourself where you sign. And that, if I burn a document with your name on it, I am in fact hurting you. In fact, this view was rather prevalent. Ever heard of voodoo?

Comment: Was that a mainstream belief or fell in the category of supernatural beliefs held by a few?

Comment: It was not fringe. It was mainstream (until Aristotelian philosophy took over). Think about the idea of an oath - it is precisely the idea that a lie (wrong signifier) hurts your soul, when uttered in the right circumstances.